# Force GNU Make rules with target specific variables to take precedence

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following Makefile that builds a small library from several source files:

```
# Source files
libABC_src := $(src_dir)/libABC_file1.c \
              $(src_dir)/libABC_file2.c \
              $(src_dir)/libABC_file3.c

# Object files
libABC_obj := $(patsubst $(src_dir)/%.c, $(obj_dir)/%.o, $(libABC_src))

# Build object files
define rule
$(libABC_obj): $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_dir)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $$@ $$<
endef
$(eval $(rule))
```

As you can see above, I have a single rule that builds all object files. This is quite neat and easy to maintain.

I have a requirement where only `libABC_file3.c` needs to be built with special compiler flags. So I looked into target specific variables, however rewriting the rule like this does not seem to work and `CFLAGS_EXTRA` is always empty when building `libABC_file3.o`:

```
# Build object files
define rule
$(obj_dir)/libABC_file3.o: private CFLAGS_EXTRA := -fno-inline
$(libABC_obj): $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_dir)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_EXTRA) -c -o $$@ $$<
endef
$(eval $(rule))
```

I assume this is because rule `$(libABC_obj): $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_dir)/%.c` already includes this target and it simply overrides the target specific rule.

I could have two separate rules - one to build `libABC_file3.o` and another to build the rest of the object files with default `CFLAGS`. However this is hard to read and maintain.

Does anyone know if GNU Make can be told to do this - "If there is a target specific rule, then it has the priority and takes precedence over any other rules with the same target". Or if there is another way to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I found the reason for the issue. Since the rule was defined and later evaluated with `eval`, I needed to escape `$` character. This is what it should look like, now with `$$(CFLAGS_EXTRA)`:

```
# Build object files
define rule
$(obj_dir)/libABC_file3.o: private CFLAGS_EXTRA := -fno-inline
$(libABC_obj): $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_dir)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $$(CFLAGS_EXTRA) -c -o $$@ $$<
endef
$(eval $(rule))
```

Not sure why variable expansion worked correctly with `$(CC)` and `$(CFLAGS)`

Comment: It works because you're not modifying those, so the value before is the same as the value afterward.  Thus it doesn't matter that these are evaluated too early since they have the same value either way.

Comment: Why do you do it this way?  Why do you have a `define` and use an `eval` on it?  There's no difference (except for this complexity around doubling `$`) to just writing the value out directly not inside a variable, and not using `eval` at all.  In general `eval` is a very advanced facility and it's not needed for straightforward situations.  And it's always a good idea to use the simplest possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The reason for me using `eval` is due to the following - this seems to be the only way to force Make to strip leading white space when it outputs recipe execution to stdout. For readability, I break up long lines with '\' character and align them with spaces or tabs. When Make executes such recipes, it passes all that white space to the shell and it looks really messy.

Comment: You could just put the content of recipe into a variable, then put the variable in the recipe.  E.g., `COMMAND := foo \\n bar \\n biz` then `$(libABC_obj): ... \n\t$(COMMAND)` and this doesn't need eval and won't have problems with extra levels of expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this out, but I don't think I will end up using it. It makes recipes look a bit disjoint, as you need to look up the definition of command before you can understand the recipe. OK, the command is likely to be on the preceding line, but it still makes it harder to read. I will just remember to use extra `$` to escape variables in define statements. It's not too bad.